# Show that $\phi_n(x) \leq \phi_{n+1}(x)$ (Folland Theorem 2.10)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, simple-functions

I am reading the proof of Theorem 2.10 in Folland's Real Analysis.

[image]

I'm stuck to show the sentence:

> It
> is easily checked that  $$\phi_n \leq \phi_{n+1}$$ for all $n$.

I first noticed that $E_{n}^{k}=E_{n+1}^{2k} \mathop{\dot{\cup}} ~ E_{n+1}^{2k+1}$.

Indeed,

\begin{eqnarray*}
x \in E_{n}^{k} &\Leftrightarrow& k2^{-n} <f(x) \leq (k+1)2^{-n}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2k2^{-(n+1)} <f(x) \leq (2k+2)2^{-(n+1)}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& f(x) \in (2k2^{-(n+1)}, (2k+1)2^{-(n+1)}] \mathop{\dot{\cup}} ((2k+1)2^{-(n+1)},(2k+1+1)2^{-(n+1)}]\\
&\Leftrightarrow&  x \in E_{n+1}^{2k} \mathop{\dot{\cup}} ~ E_{n+1}^{2k+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I would like to write
$$\phi_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{2n}-1}k2^{-n} \chi_{E_{n}^{k}}+\chi_{F_n} \hbox{ and } \phi_{n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{2(n+1)}-1}k2^{-(n+1)} \chi_{E_{n+1}^{k}}+\chi_{F_{n+1}}$$
and compare the values of $\phi_n(x)$ and $\phi_{n+1}(x)$.

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Suppose $f(x) \in (k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n],$ so that $\varphi_n(x) = k/2^n.$ This $x$ will lie in the first or second half of the interval $(k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n],$ in either case $\varphi_n(x)$ is the least of this interval while $\varphi_{n+1}(x)$ will be the least of the first or second half, so $\varphi_n(x) \leq \varphi_n(x).$ If $f(x) > 2^n,$ then $\varphi_n(x) = 2^n,$ so you divide again, if $x$ was (in fact) such that $f(x) > 2^{n+1},$ then $\varphi_{n+1}(x) = 2^{n+1},$ if $x$ was such that $2^n < f(x) \leq 2^{n+1},$ the first or second half argument applies again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if $0\leq f(x)<2^{2n}$, $\phi_n(x)$ is defined as $2^{-n}k$ where $k$ is the integer such that $k\leq 2^nf(x)<k+1$, that is $k=\lfloor 2^n f(x)\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \cdot\rfloor$ is the maximum integer function: $\lfloor t\rfloor=k\in\mathbb{Z}$ iff $k\leq t<k+1$. This all means that
$$\phi_n=\min\big(2^{-n}\lfloor 2^n f\rfloor,2^n\big)$$

Now

- If $0\leq f(x)<2^{2n}$ and  $k=\lfloor 2^nf(x)\rfloor$ then $2^{-n}k\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)$. Then, either
  $$2^{-n-1}2k=2^{-n}k\leq f(x)<\big(2^{-n}(k+1)+2^{-n}k\big)/2 = 2^{-n-1}(2k+1)$$
  or
  $$2^{-n-1}(2k+1)\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)=2^{-n-1}(2k+2)$$
  That is $2k=\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor$, or $2k+1=\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor$. This in turn means that either
  $$\phi_{n+1}(x)=2^{-n-1}\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor=2^{-n}k=\phi_n(x)$$ or $$\phi_{n+1}(x)=2^{-n-1}\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor=2^{-n-1}(2k+1)=2^{-n}k+\frac12> 2^{-n}k=\phi_n(x)$$
- If $f(x)\geq 2^{2n}$ then $2^{n+1}f(x)\geq 2^{3n+1}$ and so, $\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor \geq 2^{3n+1}$. Consequently
  $$\phi_{n+1}(x)=\min\big(2^{-n-1}\lfloor 2^{n+1}f(x)\rfloor, 2^{n+1}\big)\geq 2^{2n}=\phi_n(x)$$

Comment: I just noticed that the definition of $E_{n}^{k}$ is $\mathbf{ k2^{-n}<f(x)\leq (k+1)2^{-n}}$ and not $k2^{-n}\leq f(x) < (k+1)2^{-n}$. So I don't know if we can write this by using the maximum integer function.

Comment: Maybe we should use $\lceil 2^n f \rceil$.

Comment: No, I really mean the floor function. the ceiling function $\lceil x\rceil =\lfloor x\rfloor +1$. the author is taking the value in the left edge of the subinterval between $k2^{-n}$ and $(k+1)2^{-n}$.

Comment: In the definition of the floor function we have $k \leq x <k+1$ while in the definition of $E_{n}^{k}$ we have $k < 2^n f(x) \leq k+1$.

Comment: I think the best way to fix this problem is define $E_{n}^{k}=f^{-1}[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$. That is, change the symbol $($ by $[$ and the symbol $]$ by $)$ in the definition of $E_{n}^{k}$ and your proof doesn't change.

Comment: There are two easy fixes: (1) consider $\{2^{-n}k\leq f<2^{-n}(k+1)\}$ instead of $\{2^{-n}k<f\leq 2^{-n}(k+1)\}$ from the get-go, or notice that $\lceil x\rceil =\lfloor x\rfloor +1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The first way seems to be more correct, since in the Folland's definition $f^{-1}(0) \not\subset E_{n}^{0}$.

Comment: How did you get the 'or' part inequality? $2^{-n-1}(2k+1)\leq f(x)<2^{-n}(k+1)=2^{-n-1}(2k+2)$

Comment: @Abel: If for example $0\leq t<1$, then either $0\leq t<1/2$ to $1/2\leq t<1$.